# cannot create a new meteor app

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm a newbie and I'm getting errors while creating a new meteor app.

```
while downloading blaze
error: connect ECONNREFUSED 94.31.29.131:443
```

similar to above.

I'm running meteor from a windows machine. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: just reinstall meteor then try it. i think server side issue

Comment: What does  [https://94.31.29.131:443](https://94.31.29.131:443) return when you run it on your browser?

Comment: Thanks, this is a server side issue. My company is not allowing us to connect to that package due to security reasons,